# Localize token for different languages

Tags: antlr4, dsl

Developing a new grammar with *ANTLR*. My grammar supports basic math and boolean expressions like **"4 equals (2 minuses 2)"** or "true", "false". All operators are in natural language. I want to support other languages in their nature. For example, *"4 equals 4"* is *"4 ist 4"* in German.

What is the best practice to localize tokens and/or expressions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In our project we follow this structure. There are files `FooLexerBase.g` and `FooLexerLang1.g`, `FooLexerLang2.g` and so on. The base grammar defines common token rules. Tokens that depend on language are not defined in the base, but can be referred to. These tokens are defined in the language-specific grammars, that all also include the base.

So, basically it looks something like this:

`FooLexerBase.g`:

```
lexer grammar FooLexerBase;

...
FLOATING_POINT
    : DIGIT+                    EXPONENT
    | DIGIT+ DECIMAL_SEP DIGIT* EXPONENT?
    |        DECIMAL_SEP DIGIT+ EXPONENT?;
...
```

`DIGIT` and `EXPONENT` are defined in the base, since they are common, while `DECIMAL_SEP` is language-specific.

For example, `FooLexerGerman.g` looks like this:

```
lexer grammar FooLexerGerman;

import base = FooBase;

...
fragment
DECIMAL_SEP:  ',';
...
```

Finally, parser grammar is common for all languages. It is defined this way:

```
parser grammar FooParser;

options {
    tokenVocab = FooLexerBase;
}

...
```

It is important to *not* process `FooLexerBase` with ANTLR, but pass all other grammars through it.

At runtime you build a parser and pass an appropriate lexer as argument to the constructor. I guess it looks more or less the same in any programming language (we use Java).